# Facebook Login via parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to login Via Facebook with Parse. First of all i'm trying to just log a test message, but no log message is shown. Why is it not Printing the line test in the log? this code is connected to a UIButton . if i have the prinln code above the

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions
```

then it prints the line. How come it wont print the line inside the block when i've signed in via faceBook?

```
    var permissionArray = ["user_about_me", "user_relationships", "user_birthday", "user_location"]

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissionArray, block:  { (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) in
        println("test")

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialize should be in your AppDelegate.

And don't forget to set your applicationId!

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //other stuff

    Parse.setApplicationId("parseAppId", clientKey:"parseClientKey")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
}
```